# How to use array_push in 2D array?

Tags: php, arrays

I am having an array like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 4
            [4] => 6
            [5] => 7
            [6] => 8
            [7] => 9
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 4
            [3] => 5
            [4] => 6
            [5] => 7
            [6] => 8
            [7] => 9
            [8] => 10
            [9] => 11
        )

)
```

Now i want to put this into another array using array_push keyword...
How can i achieve this?

Comment: What you mean with another? This array and combine arrays? Create new array and appand all values to one? Be clear in your question, especially when you talk about another where you already have 3 arrays in you example code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $shiftedarray=array();
    $aftershift=array();
    foreach($twodarray as $key=>$val)
    {
        //Remove 0th index in array
        $shiftedarray[]=array_shift($val);
        //Array After Removed 0th index
        $aftershift[]=$val;

    }
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($shiftedarray);
    print_r($aftershift);
   $oneDimensionalArray = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $aftershift);

print_r($oneDimensionalArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    foreach($yourArray as $array) {
        array_push($firstArray, $array);
    }
?>
```

or

```
<?php
    foreach($yourArray as $array) {
       $firstArray[] = $array;
    }
?>
```

or

```
<?php
    array_push($firstArray, $array);
?>
```

Comment: Then write $array[0] ? Or specify your question. This are all possible things you can perform - to put one array or one array element into another.

Comment: If you just wanna remove one element from the array(here the 0th element, checkout >unset()<